# Why cant i pass in a user define value?

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

I previously posted a query as to why i could not up the gas in a script without causing the txn to fail. But i found out that its the variable i am passing in. If I pass in an amount in a string "100" the returned value assigned by `ethers.utils.parseUnits` is correct and the transaction goes through no problem. but if i assign a user defined value to a const or var and try to use that, any value over 10 results in a failed transaction.

This does not matter when obtaining a value for `gasLimit`

```
// This code will work:

const gasPriceWei = ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 'gwei');
const gas = {                                
  gasPrice: gasPriceWei,                                   
  gasLimit: gasLimit                                                      
}

// This code will NOT work:

userDefinedValue = prompt("enter the price you want to pay for gas.");

const gasPriceWei = ethers.utils.parseUnits(userDefinedValue, 'gwei');
const gas = {                                
  gasPrice: gasPriceWei,                                   
  gasLimit: gasLimit                                               
}
```

I'm just wondering why `parseUnits` chokes on a anything i pass in that's not hard coded into the script. The Value of the variable `userDefinedValue` is being obtained with prompt-sync Nodesjs prompt.

These values are being passed to:

```
 const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokens(
 0,     //dont really care about slippage
 [addresses.WBNB, token],
 addresses.target,
 Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10,                     // 10 minutes from now
 {
     ...gas,      //
     value: BNB2Swap
 }
);
```

Thank you

Comment: could you show the code that doesn't work in a more meaningful way. e.g. show how `userDefinedValue` is getting a value. Also, `console.log(userDefinedValue)` before  you call that function, does it output a meaningful value?

Comment: This is not possible. When a function receives arguments, it doesn't matter where they came from. There's no difference between literal parameters and parameters in variables. So the problem must be that the variable doesn't really contain what you think it does.

Comment: Show how you're setting `userDefinedValue` and then calling this code. I suspect there are asynchronous functions involved, and you're not doing it properly.

Comment: Really sorry about that. I meant for userDefinedValue to mean that it was a value being input at runtime. I have edited the code to show a prompt meant to define the value. Basically if i pass in a string to ethers.utils.parseUnits it works but if try to let the value be set by the user it never does.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation, `ethers.utils.parseUnits` first argument should be a string. Try to `.toString()` your user input and pass it in the function. Should work.

Now, you might want to perform a lot of user input validation before letting your users manipulate a value that could have grave financial consequences on their wallets.